# Why multiple record inserted in database, Laravel?

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent

```
DB::beginTransaction();
try {

            $data = [];
            $data['registration_number'] = $request->registration_number;
    
            $make = DB::table('vehicle_makes')->where('id',$request->make_id)->first();            
            if ($make) {
                $make_name = $make->name;
            } else {
                $make_name = $request->make_id;
            }
    
    
            $model_name = $request->model_id;
    
    
            $generation_name = $request->generation_id;
    
      
    
            $engine_name = $request->engine_id;
    
            $data['make_id'] = $make_name;
            $data['model_id'] = $model_name;
            $data['generation_id'] = $generation_name;
            $data['engine_id'] = $engine_name;
            $data['bhp'] = $request->bhp;
            $data['tool_used'] =$request->tool_used;
            $data['ecu_type'] =$request->ecu_type;
            $data['ecu_brand'] =$request->ecu_brand;
            $data['ecu_version'] =$request->ecu_version;
            $data['mileage'] =$request->mileage;
            $data['comment'] =$request->comment;
            $data['gearbox'] =$request->gearbox;
            $data['master_slave'] =$request->master_slave;
            $data['agree_to_policy'] =$request->agree_to_policy;
            $data['vehicle_type'] =$request->vehicle_type;
            $data['estimated_price'] =$request->estimated_price;
            $data['mod_request'] =json_encode($request->stage);
            $data['file_create_date'] =date('Y-m-d');
            $data['registration_status'] = 1;
            $data['file_upload_status'] = 1;
            $data['created_at'] = now();
            $data['updated_at'] = now();
            $data['is_urgent'] = $request->is_urgent ? 1 : 0;
            $file = File::find($id);
    
            $file->update($data);
    
            CreditPoint::insert([
                'user_id' => $user->id,
                'payment_gateway' => '1',
                'purchase_price' => '0',
                'txn_type' => '2',
                'credit_point' => '-'.$request->estimated_price,
                'txn_date' => date('Y-m-d'),
                'created_at' => now(),
                'created_by' => $user->id,
                'file_id' => $id,
            ]);
    
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            DB::rollBack();
            Toastr::success('File not uploaded Successfully','error');
            return redirect()->back()->with('error','File not uploaded Successfully');
        }
    
        DB::commit();
```

[look my mysql records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSKMI.png)

I am using laravel 8.75

My code is undert try catch with DB::transaction but I got 2 record same to same .

I am using laravel 8.75

My code is undert try catch but I got 2 record same to same .

We accepting one record , also it is working fine but this is first time I got this type multiple inserted records

Comment: I suppose that all the block is called two times, so also File is updated two times with the same data. I suggest you to use `DB::enableQueryLog()` and `DB::getQueryLog()` to verify how much queries are executed